# What is this IC from a Polar chest band? Top markings: TR06-3 7B227 VP712

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, components, datasheet

[image: Photo of IC]

[image: original photo] [from](http://vorticityflux.blogspot.com/2011/11/connecting-polar-wind-chest-strap-to.html)

[image: another version of PCB]

I need to find this IC datasheet, but I could not find any details on Google. It's from ST Microelectronics. Top markings: TR06-3 7B227 VP712

It's from the Polar chest band. The full PCB image above came from [here](https://www.jenrathbun.com/Electronics/disassembly/polar-bluetooth-heart-rate-monitor/).

Comment: Why do the two pictures show different devices?

Comment: @Andy - I suspect the IC photo is from the OP's PCB. The other (full PCB photo) is from someone else's webpage, linked by the OP. *komto909* - Please confirm.

Comment: @SamGibson my bad, i have updated with initial one, 2nd one I guess another version